# Is my data pre-processed correctly? My network doesn't learn and just guesses

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm currently coding a ML Vision programme to classify pictures categorially.
My CNN doesn't learn at all and just guesses the output.

```
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import random
random.seed(40)

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(40)  # for reproducibility

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow as tf


path_labels = '/Users/felix/Desktop/Daten/Labels.xlsx'


#import label data and construct label data frame
workbook = load_workbook(path_labels)
features = []
labels = []
for row in range (2, workbook['Sheet1' ].max_row+1):
    cell_Bezeichnung = workbook ['Sheet1']["{}{}".format('A', row) ].value
    cell_Label = workbook['Sheet1']["{}{}".format("B",row)].value

    features.append(str(cell_Bezeichnung)+'.JPG')
    labels.append(str(cell_Label))

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'Datei': features, 'Label': labels})
data = shuffle(data)
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
#one hot encoding
targets = data
targets = targets.drop('Datei', 1)
targets = pd.get_dummies(targets)

print(targets.head())

files = data.drop('Label', 1)

print (files.head())

from keras.preprocessing import image                  
from tqdm import tqdm
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
path_images = '/Users/felix/Desktop/Daten/Bilddaten_zugeschnitten/'
def path_to_tensor(img_path):
    # loads RGB image as PIL.Image.Image type
    img_path = path_images+img_path

    img = image.load_img(img_path.item(0), target_size=(224, 224)) #Variation mit mehr als 100x100 pixel
    #tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img,name=None)

    # convert PIL.Image.Image type to 3D tensor with shape (224, 224, 3)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    # convert 3D tensor to 4D tensor with shape (1, 224, 224, 3) and return 4D tensor
    return np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)


def paths_to_tensor(img_paths):
    list_of_tensors = [path_to_tensor(img_path) for img_path in tqdm(img_paths)]
    return np.vstack(list_of_tensors)

#ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

# pre-process the data for Keras
tensors = paths_to_tensor(files.values).astype('float32')/255

testing_share = 0.3 #0.01
testing_index = tensors.shape[0] - round(tensors.shape[0]*testing_share)
x_test, y_test = tensors[testing_index:], targets[testing_index:]
x_train, y_train = tensors[:testing_index], targets[:testing_index]

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv3D, GlobalMaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, GlobalMaxPooling3D, AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential




model = Sequential()


### Define architecture.
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, strides=(1,1),padding="same",input_shape=(224,224,3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, strides=(2,2),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, strides=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D(data_format=None))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(y_test.shape[1], activation="softmax"))

#dropouts sind layer die funkionen deaktivieren
#netzwerk soll lernen, weiter zu arbeiten, wenn kernel sterben

model.summary()


# compile the model

import keras

from keras import optimizers

from keras.optimizers import SGD


from keras.optimizers import rmsprop


from keras.optimizers import adam

#optimizer = optimizers.sgd(lr=0.0001,) #0.1
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
 metrics=['accuracy'])

error = model.predict(x_test)

print(error)

[[0.25006285 0.24996501 0.25002083 0.24995136]
 [0.25008076 0.24997567 0.2500124  0.24993122]
 [0.2500582  0.24996252 0.2500291  0.2499501 ]
 [0.25007743 0.2499672  0.25001416 0.2499412 ]
 [0.25007534 0.24996328 0.25002202 0.24993943]
 [0.25008073 0.24996676 0.25001672 0.2499358 ]
 [0.25007495 0.2499676  0.2500172  0.24994019]
 [0.2500594  0.24995789 0.250027   0.24995567]
 [0.25008485 0.2499618  0.25001773 0.24993569]
 [0.25007278 0.24996817 0.25001302 0.2499461 ]
 [0.25007483 0.2499688  0.25001898 0.2499374 ]
 [0.25008535 0.24996835 0.25001317 0.24993314]
 [0.25007445 0.24996167 0.25001654 0.2499473 ]
 [0.2500802  0.24997373 0.2500132  0.24993286]
 [0.25007555 0.24996133 0.25003204 0.24993111]
 [0.25007793 0.24997222 0.25001374 0.24993618]
 [0.25005803 0.24997807 0.2500176  0.24994631]
 [0.2500784  0.24996012 0.25001165 0.24994987]
 [0.2500772  0.24996161 0.25001106 0.24995017]
 [0.2500813  0.2499702  0.2500116  0.24993694]
 [0.25007752 0.24997033 0.25001392 0.24993823]
 [0.25007617 0.24996412 0.25001463 0.24994507]
 [0.25007036 0.24997123 0.25001976 0.24993876]
 [0.25007662 0.2499671  0.25001895 0.2499373 ]
 [0.25007728 0.24996927 0.2500137  0.24993978]
 [0.2500731  0.2499717  0.25001666 0.2499386 ]
 [0.2500792  0.24997078 0.25001392 0.24993607]
 [0.2500816  0.2499651  0.25001276 0.24994059]
 [0.25007784 0.24995804 0.2500315  0.2499326 ]
 [0.25007495 0.24995953 0.2500203  0.24994528]
 [0.25007513 0.24995038 0.25003663 0.24993785]
 [0.25008193 0.24995089 0.25002486 0.24994227]
 [0.25006574 0.24995221 0.2500334  0.24994862]
 [0.25007313 0.24997073 0.2500068  0.2499494 ]
 [0.25007546 0.24996972 0.25002092 0.2499339 ]
 [0.2500602  0.24995638 0.25002822 0.24995506]
 [0.25007087 0.24998225 0.25001073 0.24993609]
 [0.25009194 0.24996428 0.25000528 0.24993849]
 [0.25007385 0.24997565 0.2500184  0.24993216]
 [0.25007346 0.24996477 0.25002295 0.24993882]
 [0.25006285 0.24995741 0.25003105 0.24994871]
 [0.25007546 0.24997638 0.25001225 0.24993594]
 [0.25006792 0.24995044 0.25003865 0.24994306]
 [0.25008726 0.24996646 0.25001788 0.24992841]
 [0.25007448 0.24997017 0.25001752 0.2499378 ]
 [0.25007167 0.24996181 0.25001797 0.24994862]
 [0.25008237 0.24996439 0.25000966 0.24994355]
 [0.2500695  0.24996364 0.25002092 0.24994592]
 [0.25007692 0.2499711  0.25001416 0.24993788]
 [0.2500824  0.24996519 0.25000864 0.24994376]
 [0.2500767  0.24996592 0.25001433 0.24994306]
 [0.2500684  0.24995859 0.25003484 0.2499382 ]
 [0.25007054 0.24996616 0.25001797 0.24994533]
 [0.25009173 0.24996561 0.25000745 0.24993522]
 [0.25008002 0.24996746 0.2500147  0.24993786]
 [0.2500748  0.24996786 0.25000873 0.24994864]
 [0.2500774  0.24997115 0.25001118 0.24994026]
 [0.25006884 0.24996077 0.25002298 0.24994741]
 [0.25005615 0.24995732 0.25003523 0.24995126]
 [0.25007707 0.24996826 0.25001627 0.24993831]
 [0.25008127 0.24996836 0.25001183 0.24993852]
 [0.25007385 0.2499684  0.2500187  0.24993904]
 [0.25006378 0.24997012 0.2500189  0.24994728]
 [0.2500762  0.24997364 0.25001153 0.24993856]
 [0.25008038 0.24995975 0.2500139  0.24994597]
 [0.2500857  0.2499656  0.25000656 0.24994215]
 [0.25008604 0.24996783 0.25001597 0.24993013]
 [0.25006878 0.24996276 0.25002745 0.24994111]
 [0.25007826 0.24996968 0.2500182  0.24993387]
 [0.2500698  0.24997027 0.2500128  0.24994715]
 [0.25007647 0.24996483 0.25001547 0.24994324]
 [0.25008276 0.24996983 0.25001243 0.24993502]
 [0.2500697  0.24997318 0.2500129  0.24994427]
 [0.2500747  0.24996682 0.2500108  0.24994765]
 [0.250073   0.24996653 0.25001878 0.24994177]
 [0.2500709  0.24997084 0.25001994 0.24993828]
 [0.25006709 0.24997054 0.2500242  0.24993815]
 [0.25008497 0.24996297 0.25001696 0.249935  ]
 [0.2500651  0.24995178 0.25003874 0.24994442]
 [0.25007528 0.24996938 0.2500194  0.24993595]
 [0.25007984 0.2499677  0.25001895 0.2499335 ]
 [0.25008506 0.24996516 0.25001836 0.24993142]
 [0.250082   0.24996546 0.25001726 0.24993534]
 [0.25006655 0.24996561 0.25002077 0.24994712]
 [0.25007233 0.24997492 0.25001252 0.24994019]
 [0.250074   0.24996708 0.25000945 0.24994949]
 [0.25008136 0.24995574 0.25002033 0.24994257]
 [0.2500709  0.24996184 0.2500229  0.24994433]
 [0.25007755 0.24995202 0.25003335 0.249937  ]
 [0.2500736  0.24997254 0.250015   0.24993886]
 [0.25006583 0.24996303 0.2500226  0.2499486 ]
 [0.25007483 0.24997738 0.25001508 0.24993278]
 [0.2500662  0.24996226 0.2500349  0.24993668]
 [0.2500774  0.24996667 0.25001344 0.24994245]
 [0.25006792 0.24995145 0.25003457 0.2499461 ]
 [0.2500603  0.24995281 0.2500334  0.24995343]
 [0.250059   0.24995674 0.25003695 0.24994728]
 [0.2500626  0.24996206 0.25002703 0.24994832]
 [0.25007066 0.24996097 0.25002307 0.2499453 ]
 [0.2500736  0.24997665 0.2500144  0.24993531]
 [0.25008708 0.24997056 0.25001645 0.2499259 ]
 [0.25005743 0.24996099 0.25002706 0.24995449]
 [0.250062   0.24998043 0.2500229  0.24993478]
 [0.25006992 0.24996766 0.25001696 0.24994548]
 [0.25007722 0.24996564 0.2500146  0.24994259]
 [0.25008243 0.24997042 0.2500136  0.24993362]
 [0.25006735 0.24996237 0.25002933 0.24994104]
 [0.25006872 0.24995397 0.2500326  0.24994478]
 [0.2500679  0.24996191 0.2500241  0.24994612]
 [0.25009197 0.24995779 0.2500152  0.24993509]
 [0.25008324 0.24996872 0.25001323 0.24993473]
 [0.25007743 0.24997263 0.25000903 0.24994095]
 [0.2500631  0.2499686  0.25003257 0.24993584]
 [0.25006607 0.24996045 0.25002548 0.24994805]
 [0.25005895 0.24998237 0.25001976 0.24993889]
 [0.25006407 0.2499555  0.25003356 0.24994694]
 [0.25006366 0.24995647 0.25002795 0.24995202]
 [0.25008795 0.24997298 0.25001886 0.24992022]
 [0.25005513 0.2499775  0.25001684 0.24995047]
 [0.25007448 0.24996139 0.25002256 0.24994159]
 [0.25006628 0.24997294 0.25002363 0.24993722]
 [0.2500835  0.24996667 0.2500097  0.24994011]
 [0.25006843 0.24995919 0.2500261  0.24994628]
 [0.25007316 0.24997073 0.25001794 0.24993816]
 [0.25008273 0.2499673  0.25001198 0.2499379 ]
 [0.2500748  0.24997313 0.25001442 0.2499376 ]
 [0.250075   0.24997061 0.25001994 0.2499345 ]
 [0.2500757  0.24997036 0.25001526 0.24993867]
 [0.250078   0.2499685  0.25000528 0.2499482 ]
 [0.25007048 0.24994877 0.2500401  0.24994063]
 [0.25006124 0.2499642  0.25001806 0.24995647]
 [0.2500705  0.2499617  0.25001982 0.24994802]
 [0.2500815  0.24996363 0.25000906 0.2499458 ]
 [0.25006425 0.24996895 0.25001505 0.24995178]
 [0.25007218 0.24997188 0.25002077 0.24993512]
 [0.25007123 0.24997196 0.2500212  0.24993564]
 [0.25006527 0.2499646  0.25001764 0.24995254]
 [0.25007126 0.24995747 0.25002196 0.2499494 ]
 [0.2500677  0.24995501 0.2500297  0.24994752]
 [0.2500733  0.24996659 0.2500171  0.24994294]
 [0.25007385 0.2499434  0.2500364  0.24994639]
 [0.25006333 0.24996033 0.25002643 0.24994989]
 [0.25007668 0.24996741 0.25001174 0.24994417]
 [0.25006187 0.24995287 0.25003016 0.24995513]
 [0.2500838  0.24996549 0.25001827 0.2499324 ]
 [0.25008044 0.24996719 0.25001672 0.24993567]
 [0.25007057 0.24995601 0.25002605 0.24994737]
 [0.2500773  0.24997096 0.25001264 0.24993913]
 [0.2500796  0.24997199 0.25000918 0.24993925]
 [0.2500773  0.2499672  0.25001302 0.24994251]
 [0.25007573 0.24997133 0.25000885 0.2499441 ]
 [0.25006795 0.24996015 0.2500245  0.24994741]
 [0.25007918 0.24996641 0.25001818 0.24993613]
 [0.25007203 0.24996912 0.25000858 0.24995026]
 [0.25007164 0.24996807 0.2500243  0.24993607]
 [0.2500733  0.249961   0.25001734 0.24994832]
 [0.2500638  0.24996074 0.25002792 0.24994762]
 [0.25007963 0.2499707  0.2500181  0.24993162]
 [0.25008625 0.24996635 0.2500065  0.24994084]
 [0.25008115 0.24996302 0.250018   0.24993783]
 [0.25007886 0.2499649  0.25001216 0.24994412]
 [0.25007793 0.24997391 0.2500138  0.24993435]
 [0.2500758  0.24996938 0.2500197  0.24993521]
 [0.25008273 0.24996585 0.25001657 0.2499349 ]
 [0.25006455 0.24997023 0.25001556 0.24994972]
 [0.25007576 0.24996512 0.2500098  0.24994932]
 [0.2500829  0.24997182 0.25001445 0.24993081]
 [0.2500687  0.24997266 0.25001624 0.24994251]
 [0.25007847 0.24997012 0.25000468 0.24994673]
 [0.25006625 0.24996042 0.25002444 0.24994884]
 [0.25007161 0.24996774 0.25001383 0.24994685]
 [0.25006938 0.2499722  0.25001884 0.24993967]
 [0.2500708  0.24997376 0.2500203  0.24993515]
 [0.25008178 0.24996838 0.25001445 0.24993533]
 [0.25008288 0.24996988 0.25000745 0.24993972]
 [0.25007623 0.249967   0.25000775 0.24994898]
 [0.25007024 0.24996075 0.25003254 0.24993643]
 [0.2500883  0.2499763  0.2500102  0.24992523]
 [0.2500711  0.24995194 0.25002965 0.24994734]
 [0.25008234 0.2499697  0.25001442 0.24993351]]

new_model = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                      batch_size=32, epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

Fixes tried:

- changed the LR from 0.01 to 0.00000001
- changed Pixels from 20x20 to 1000x1000
- changed batch_size
- changed epochs
- changed optimizer
- changed activation from sigmoid to softmax
- changed layer
- added batch_normalization
- added pooling layers
- added augmentation
- used different test sizes

Any kind of held is very appreciated!

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Did you change the batch size to a smaller size? say 8 or 16 batch?

Comment: Have you trained the model before predicting.? I can't see `model.fit()` in your code before predicting. From your code what I can see is that you defined the model, compiled it and then predicted. After that you are training the model with `model.fit`. Is it a copy paste error.?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling model.predict() before you call model.fit()

Model.fit is where the training occurs, so you are trying to predict data on an untrained model. It's the last line in your code -- do it immediately after your model.compile() call instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model doesn't have an Input layer, so it probably doesn't even see the images.